# Marketing cloud > content builder > content items

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have two users having same access content builder , Email, cloud pages in permission set but one user can see more content items and one less, i can see business unit is also same for both.

What may be the reason ? ca

Comment: With what kind of content you have this issue? Are shared content?

Comment: it is local content

Answer (score 0):

Check that they both have the [Content Creator role](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_email_studio_roles.htm&type=5) (out-of-the-box).

Go to **Email Studio > Email > Admin > My Users**

Click the checkbox next to the user and click the **Manage Roles** button in the toolbar

Comment: other user who can see more content also dont have content creator still he can see more records. both have role marketing cloud channel manager.

Comment: Go under users and manage role and under the role see if there are any additional checkboxes checked